# Writing JUNIT test case for the class that has RequestDispatcher and HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, junit, servlet-filters

I have a Filter class similar to this.

My class

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (isMockAccountEnabled()) {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String reqUrl = req.getRequestURI();
        ApiUserDetails userDetails = userBean.getUserDetails();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        if (isThisTestAccount(reqUrl, session)) {

            log.debug("Entering Test acount flow for the request " + reqUrl);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/mock/" + EnumService.returnMockService(reqUrl));
            dispatcher.forward(request, resp);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to write the JUNIT test case to it.

I have tried similar to this.

Test case written

```
@Mock
private FilterChain chain;


@InjectMocks
private MockAccountFilter mockAccountFilter = new MockAccountFilter();


MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
@Test
public void filterRequestMockFirst()
    throws Exception
{
    MockRequestDispatcher dispatcher =new MockRequestDispatcher("/mock/ABCTEST");
    when(request.getRequestDispatcher("/mock/ABCTEST")).thenReturn(dispatcher);
    request.setRequestURI("/check/employee/123456/false");
    mockAccountFilter.doFilter(request, response, chain);  
    Assert.assertTrue(request.getRequestURI().contains("/mock/ABCTEST"));

}
```

I am new to writing test cases.

I not able to figure out how do it in proper way.

I get error message as

**Error**

```
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Can some one suggest me best way writing test case for above class.